# Multiple CD writer taking long to burn

Tags: performance, burning, compact-disc

I have installed 6 DVD writers in Tower case.

I am using Alcohol Software to burn multiple CDS.

I have seen that about 4 dvd/cd writer finish recording early but some take long time finish and their speed is around 7x. Its not that those are the only writers doing that, some times other writer write slowly. But there are always 1 or 2 writer which takes about 25 min to write the 700Mb cd and some finish in 5 mins

Why is that. All writers can write upto 40px speed.
Which thing determines the speed

Comment: are you burning multiple CDs simultaneously?  or one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a data transfer bottleneck somewhere along the chain.  Could be the bus, the HD, etc.  Assuming that you're using Windows, you can use perfmon to set some performance counters and see what you can figure out.

Comment: What is that perfmon , how can i use it

Comment: Windows > Run > perfmon. It's not on Windows XP or ealier however. (Full name is the Reliability and Performance monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes optical drives revert to the slow PIO mode instead of DMA, typically because they encountered a scratched or damaged disc at some point.  See [this page](http://winhlp.com/node/10) for more information and a VB Script to correct the problem.